# REST request blocked when executed in an `@SpringBootTest` but not when I run the application?

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, jax-rs, vaadin

I have a Spring Boot application with a Jersey REST api at `/rest`:

```java
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public RestApplication(){
        packages("ch.cypherk.myapp.service.rest");
    }
}
```

this here is the controller that should allow a user to log in:

```
@Service
@Path("/login")
class LoginRestController
@Inject constructor(
    private val authenticationService: MyAuthenticationProvider
) {

    @Operation(summary = "Login user, use cookie JSESSIONID in response header for further requests authentication.",
        requestBody = RequestBody(description = "Login credentials of user.", required = true,
            content = [Content(schema = Schema(implementation = LoginDto::class))]),
        responses = [
            ApiResponse(responseCode = "202", description = "Login successful."),
            ApiResponse(responseCode = "403", description = "Invalid credentials supplied.")])
    @POST
    fun postLogin(loginCredentials: LoginDto) {
        val auth = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginCredentials.username,loginCredentials.password)
        authenticationService.authenticate(auth)
    }
}
```

Where

```
@Service
class MyAuthenticationProvider (
    ...
): AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider() {

    @Transactional
    override fun authenticate(authentication: Authentication?): Authentication {
        return super.authenticate(authentication)
    }
    ...
}
```

is just a custom implementation that adds a bunch of extra checks.

If I start up the Spring Boot application and use postman to make a post request to `http://localhost:8080/rest/login` and with valid credentials, everything works as intended.

However, if I try to write a test for it,

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest
import io.restassured.RestAssured.given
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus.*
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
class LoginRestControllerIT {

    @Test
    fun login() {
        given()
            .contentType("application/json")
            .body(LoginDto("testuserA", "secret"))
        .When()
            .post("/rest/login")

        .then()
            .statusCode(SC_NO_CONTENT)
            .cookie("JSESSIONID")
    }
}
```

it gives me an error because I expected `204` (no content) response code and got an `403` (forbidden).

***Why?***

The above code is using [RestAssured](http://rest-assured.io/), but the issue isn't due to the framework as I've tried rewriting the test with [Unirest](http://unirest.io/),

```
val response = Unirest.post("http://localhost:8080/rest/login")
    .field("username","testuserA")
    .field("password","secret")
    .asJson()

assertThat(response.status).isEqualTo(SC_NO_CONTENT)
```

and got the same error.

I've set a breakpoint at the first statement in my `LoginRestController`'s `login` function and it is NOT reached. Which means something somewhere earlier in the chain already rejects the request

My security config looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableVaadin
@EnableVaadinSharedSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    securedEnabled = true,
    prePostEnabled = true,
    proxyTargetClass = true
)
class VaadinAwareSecurityConfiguration @Inject constructor(
    private val authenticationProvider:AuthenticationProvider
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {


    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/rest/login/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/UIDL/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/HEARTBEAT/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler())
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?goodbye").permitAll()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
    }

    override fun configure(web: WebSecurity) {
        web
            .ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/VAADIN/**"
            )
    }

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
    }

    private fun logoutHandler(): LogoutHandler {
        return VaadinSessionClosingLogoutHandler()
    }

    @Bean
    fun myAuthenticationManager(): AuthenticationManager {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean()
    }
}
```

***UPDATE***

So it looks like it's the `org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter` that ends up throwing an `AccessDeniedException` because the csrf token is missing ... but it shouldn't do that as I've disabled Spring's csrf protection ...

Comment: Why are you using JAX-RS with Spring Boot?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli because we're migrating a thorntail application to spring boot and don't want to change too much at once. We probably will switch to Spring MVC at a later point in time, but for now, the priority lies with getting JAX-RS to work.

Comment: You have disabled basic and form login. How do you login to your application?