# How do you disable VAADIN's csrf protection in Spring?

Tags: spring, vaadin, csrf, csrf-protection, vaadin8

Ok, so I *think* [my other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541326/rest-request-blocked-when-executed-in-an-springboottest-but-not-when-i-run-th) can be broken down to two scenarios.

- my security configuration is not applied to my integration test, or
- vaadin's shared security csrf protection is also making use of the `org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter`

  - (which is where the access denied exception eventually occurs, despite Csrf protection being turned off in the settings)

How do you turn *off* ***VAADIN***'s csrf protection, though?

The only thing I found was for Vaadin 7 (we're using 8) and [with a web.xml](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/653#issuecomment-266026480) (that we don't have with Spring Boot).

Comment: Are you using Spring or Spring Boot?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Spring Boot

Comment: Why did you create two questions for the same?

Comment: I didn't? These are two separate issues that happen to be related.

Comment: No I think this is the same

Comment: Have you tried using `@WebInitParam` for a `@WebServlet` configuration?
like this:
`initParams = {@WebInitParam(name = "disable-xsrf-protection", value = "true")}`. Example is from here: [Load testing with Gatling](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/articles/LoadTestingWithGatling.html)